# bounded linear operator and norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is a non zero bounded linear operator and $\alpha\geq 0$. Show that
$$\inf\{\|x\|:\|F(x)\|=\alpha\}=\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}.$$

For all $x\in X$ we have $\|F(x)\|\leq \|F\|\|x\|$.

For $x\in X$ such that $\|F(x)\|=\alpha$ we have $\alpha\leq \|F\|\|x\|$ i.e., $\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}\leq \|x\|$

So, we have $$\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}\leq \inf\{\|x\|:\|F(x)\|=\alpha\}.$$

To prove the equality, i search for an element $x\in  X$ with $||F(x)||=\alpha$ and $\|x\|=\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}$

As $F$ is nonzero, there exists $y\in X$ such that $F(y)\neq 0$.

Consider the element $x=\frac{\alpha y}{\|F(y)\|}$. For this, $\|F(x)\|=\alpha$. But this does not give $\|x\|=\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}$

Help me to complete this.

Comment: In general there won't be an $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=\frac{\alpha}{\|F\|}$.  You'll have to rely on some supremum-infimum properties.

Comment: I understand that there wont be such $x$ in general.. coudl not think beyond @Aweygan

Comment: Try simplifying the problem by letting $\alpha=1$, then generalize.

Comment: @Aweygan :  I will try..

Answer (score 1):

$$
||F|| = \sup_{||x||=1}||F(x)||
$$
implies

$$
1 = \inf\{||x||:||F(x)||=||F||\}
$$

and for any $\lambda \gt 0$
$$
\lambda = \inf\{||x||:||F(x)||=\lambda||F||\}
$$
now set $\lambda = \frac{\alpha}{||F||}$ to obtain the required result

Comment: This is a good answer.. But to fill the gap, i am sure i will end up with same problem as i had in my question

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \underbrace{\inf \{ M \mid \|Fx\| \le M\|x\|, \  \forall x \in X \}}_{:=I_1} \le  \underbrace{\inf \{ M \mid \|Fx\| \le M\|x\| \text{ for all } x \in X \text{ such that } \alpha = \|Fx\| \}}_{:=I_2}$$

By definition of inf, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $x \in X$ with $\alpha = \|Fx\|$  such that $$(I_2 - \epsilon) \|x\| \le \|F(x)\|=\alpha
\implies (I_1 - \epsilon) \le (I_2 - \epsilon) \le \dfrac{\alpha}{\|x\|} \le \dfrac{\alpha}{\inf\{\|x\|:\|F(x)\|=\alpha\}}$$

and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we get $I_1  \le \dfrac{\alpha}{\inf\{\|x\|:\|F(x)\|=\alpha\}}$. But $I_1 = \|F\|_{op}  $. QED